# e.CommandArgument error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

```
 CMS.Data.HMSDataContext db = new Data.HMSDataContext();
 string indexx = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

Here is my code 
I found an error of  "e.CommandArgument"

Error statement Is: System.eventargs does not contain defination of CommandArgument missing some refrence

Comment: You are using this snippet in which event ?

Comment: i am using this in button_click Event

Comment: Error 14 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'CommandArgument' and no extension method 'CommandArgument' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Is that button inside grid/ any other parent controls? could you please include the event signature?

Comment: Let me guess. You are handling a command event of a gridview or repeater? If so, do not handle click on the button that sends the command, handle the RowCommand (or ItemCommand) event of this gridview/repeater instead. Also make sure to declare right type for event args, just `EventArgs` is not sufficient obviously, as it does not define `CommandArgument`

Comment: I am using it in Button Event so can i use it in Button Event ?

Answer (score 0):

(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)

Your function should have above parameters for it to function correctly